# flash builder 4.6 and sqlite location

Tags: flash, sqlite, location, directory, builder

I am developing an app for iPad 3rd using Flash builder 4.6 with an embedded sqlite database.
Before compiling procedure I copied database in assets folder: on emulator it goes fine but on iPad procedure is unable to retrieve data without errors. 
This is the instruction to open database:

stmt.sqlConnection.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("/Users/me/Downloads/test.sqlite"));

Tried also to change to

stmt.sqlConnection.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("assets/test.sqlite"));

and, after testing it, changed again to

stmt.sqlConnection.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("test.sqlite"));

but no luck: what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself: 
place in front of all

```
var dbFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("db/test.sqlite");
var dbWorkFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("test.sqlite");

if(!dbWorkFile.exists){
    dbFile.copyTo(dbWorkFile);
}
```

connection has to be modified in

```
stmt.sqlConnection.open(File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("test.sqlite"));
```

Tip found on
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Including_a_database_in_an_Adobe_AIR_application-17721.html